# Number-theoretic function using Table

Tags: functions, function-construction, number-theory

I'm trying to make a function to calculate the Log sum of primes over a limited range $1/2n$ to $n$ or Chebychev theta function over limited range $1/2n$ to $n$. This will be used *only* for even numbers.

To start off I'm trying to modify a function that works:

```
LogSumPrime[n_] := Total[Log[Table[Prime[i], {i, PrimePi[n]}]]];
```

this will output as desired for `LogSumPrime[12]`:

```
Log[2] + Log[3] + Log[5] + Log[7] + Log[11]
```

So far so good. Now modifying to get range $1/2n$ to $n$:

```
LogSumAllUpperPrime[n_] := 
  Total[Log[Table[(Prime[i + PrimePi[n] - PrimePi[n/2] + 1]), 
  {i, PrimePi[n] - PrimePi[n/2]}]]];
```

for `LogSumAllUpperPrime[12]`, it is fine:

```
Log[7] + Log[11]
```

for `LogSumAllUpperPrime[6]`, it is not fine:

```
Log[5]
```

It should be `Log[3] + Log[5]`. Now the problem stems from half of 6 being odd and the limits not starting for this at 3, while for 12 it starts at 6 and the problem does not matter.

I do not understand Mathematica, so I cannot see how to solve this problem efficiently. If it were C, I'd just see if the bit is 1 or 0 to determine whether its even, but that may not be the best remedy here.

I would like to do this quite efficiently as I will be working with quite large numbers and the `Table` approach is said to be reasonably efficient.

Comment: If `primePi` was input correctly then it depends on how that function is defined. If it was intended to be `PrimePi[n/2]` then possibly use of `Floor` or `Ceiling` will remedy the issue.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau I thought this initially too but this is not an issue since only even numbers are used so it made no difference when I tried so I removed it from the code. The actual problem is when half the n is an odd number.

Comment: Please post the definition of `primePi`

Comment: @m_goldberg primePi  is a typo by somebody will rectify

Comment: Then perhaps *It should be `Log[3] Log[5]`* should be *It should be `Log[3] + Log[5]`*

Comment: Or when n/2 is prime... Could use `Table[Prime[i + PrimePi[n/2] - Boole[PrimeQ[n/2]]], {i, PrimePi[n] - PrimePi[n/2] + Boole[PrimeQ[n/2]]}]`

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau yes that works nicely and would do as an additional answer thanks.

Comment: Asymptotically this approaches `n/2`. It has been a long time since I saw this nifty function (like, three decades). I had forgotten all about it, and the relation to PNT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you mean

```
LogSumPrime[n_] := Total@Log@Prime@Range@PrimePi@n

LogSumAllUpperPrime[n_] := 
 Total@Log@Prime@Range[Max[1, PrimePi[n/2]], PrimePi@n]

{#, LogSumPrime[#], LogSumAllUpperPrime[#]} & /@ Range[2, 12, 2] // 
  Prepend[#, Style[#, Bold] & /@ {"n", LogSumPrime, LogSumAllUpperPrime}] & //
  Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Based on your comment, you apparently intend

```
LogSumAllUpperPrime[n_] := Total@Log@Select[Prime@Range@PrimePi@n, # >= n/2 &]

{#, LogSumPrime[#], LogSumAllUpperPrime[#]} & /@ Range[2, 12, 2] // 
  Prepend[#, Style[#, Bold] & /@ {"n", LogSumPrime, LogSumAllUpperPrime}] & //
  Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

Comment: not quite I think LogSumAllUpperPrime[] with 8  and 12 should start at Log[5] and Log[7] otherwise it includes partial sums < n/2

Comment: yes that's it, thanks.